# Webbrowser.document won't update

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to develop an app that has to interact with a Web page.

I used the builtin webbrowser to fill a first form and submit it. No problem here.

When clicking this form, the page loads a diferent html code(a second step on the form) withing the same page. It doesn't fire the document completed event, and what is worse, it doesn't change the document item. The documenttext item has the new code, the page shows perfectly on the form, but the document item still holds the old code. I can't click the second button without the document.

So, 2 questions.

Is there a way to force the document to load the new html code so I can just click it?

Is there a way to click that button without using Htmlelement.InvokeMember?

```
Private Sub login()
  Browser.Navigate("website")
  docflag.WaitOne()
  docflag.Reset()
  Dim inputs As HtmlElementCollection = document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
  Dim login As HtmlElement = Nothing
  For Each item As HtmlElement In inputs
    Select Case item.Id
      Case "nick"
        item.SetAttribute("value", TBUsuario.Text)
      Case "pass"
        item.SetAttribute("value", TBPass.Text)
      Case ""
        Dim src As String = item.GetAttribute("src")
        If src.IndexOf("/login.gif") <> -1 Then
         login = item
        End If
    End Select
  Next
  Conecta(True)
  login.InvokeMember("click")
  docflag.WaitOne()
   docflag.Reset()
  'msg(document.Body.OuterHtml) returns code of the first page
  'msg(document.documenttext) returns code of the actual page   
  document.GetelementById("identrar" + TBCodigo.Text).InvokeMember("click")
  docflag.WaitOne()
  docflag.Reset()
End Sub

Private Sub Browser_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As      WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles Browser.DocumentCompleted
document = Browser.Document
docflag.Set()
msg("Pagina cargada")
End Sub
```

Edited to include some of the code. I read while trying to fix this that i should use a single thread while working with webbrowser but that doesn't seem to be the problem(I tried it on a single thread and the document doesn't change either)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide some sample code that isn't working the way you want?

Comment: edite to includ some of the code. Right now I'm fairly lost, since the only alternative option i see to using this element is sending the post message myself and that gets messy quickly

Comment: You cannot call WaitOne() on the UI thread.  Blocking the UI thread prevents the DocumentCompleted event from being fired.  Your code needs to be moved to the DocumentCompleted event.  Use a variable to keep track of the state.

Comment: I don't call Waitone in the ui thread. sub Login works in a different thread. The code is working perfectly, and I can load everypage. The problem is when the page has variable content on it, I get the initial code(with an empty div called variable content), and the document doesn't change to reflect any changes, so I can't use any of the elements declared in the varible content div

Comment: Editing to say "Solved" isn't how StackOverflow works. If you've reached a solution on your own, you should post it as an answer instead. Answering your own question here is perfectly fine, and is mentioned in the [faq] in the section about posting answers. You can even accept your own answer as correct. (You won't gain any rep for either of those, but it clearly shows you've arrived at a solution and provides it for future readers here.) I'm rolling back your last edit for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

First use `webbrowser.Navigate("about:blank");`

Comment: Can't really do that. Maybe I didn't explain myself well. I load the first page, then use item.invokemember, and that loads the second one. If I load about:blank inbetween I won't be able to call it.